# Editing a flagged comment from the queue causes it to disappear but reappear on reload

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, comment-flags

Observe:

---

## 1.

> [image: step 1]

---

## 2.

> [image: step 2]

---

## 3.

> (*hit enter, flag disappears*)

---

## 4.

> (*refresh*)
>
> [image: step 4]

---

I believe there are two bugs at play here:

1. The comment flag is hidden from the flag queue after editing it, but it's still actually there (and reappears when the page is refreshed).
2. Editing a comment from the flag queue should automatically dismiss the comment flag as helpful anyway. I think I recall this being the case previously, and others seem to agree as well.

The first is likely caused by the second, since locally the site thinks the flag is supposed to have been cleared as helpful, but it hasn't actually been marked as helpful and dismissed on the server-side.